# Pyqt5 QMediaPlayer.position после проигрывания не соответствует реальной позиции в видео

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, pyqt

Я хочу сделать покадровый переход по видеофайлу, но проблема в том, что после проигрывания, достаточно пары секунд, реальная позиция видео не соответствует значению из QMediaPlayer.position(), а именно отставание на 1-2 кадра. Это легко наблюдается если проиграть видео с каким нибудь счетчиком или быстрыми действиями. При этом если продолжить проигрывать видео сняв его с паузы без перехода, плеер ожидаемо продолжает с места остановки.

Для теста выкладываю рабочий скрипт, который по нажатии кнопки "Seek to current position" позволяет перейти на текущую позицию полученную из QMediaPlay.position().

Буду благодарен любым ответам и возможности решения этой проблемы.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl, QSize
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaContent, QMediaPlayer
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget


class VideoWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(500, 500))
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 500, 500)

        self.mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.centralWidget.setLayout(self.mainLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        video_widget = QVideoWidget()
        button = QPushButton('Play', self)
        button.clicked.connect(self.playMedia)

        button2 = QPushButton("Seek to current position", self)
        button2.clicked.connect(self.seekToCurrentPosition)

        self.mainLayout.addWidget(video_widget)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(button)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(button2)

        self.mediaPlayer = QMediaPlayer(None, QMediaPlayer.VideoSurface)
        self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(video_widget)
        self.mediaPlayer.setMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile("1.mp4")))

    def playMedia(self):
        if self.mediaPlayer.state() == QMediaPlayer.PlayingState:
            self.mediaPlayer.pause()
            print("current_position: ", self.mediaPlayer.position())
        else:
            self.mediaPlayer.play()

    def seekToCurrentPosition(self):
        if self.mediaPlayer.state() != QMediaPlayer.PausedState:
            return

        current_pos = self.mediaPlayer.position()
        self.mediaPlayer.setPosition(current_pos)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    player = VideoWindow()
    player.show()

    exitCode = app.exec_()
    sys.exit(exitCode)
```

Answer (score 1):

С трудом понял о чем вы говорите
и то после кучи принтов и установления сигнала

```
self.mediaPlayer.positionChanged.connect(self.positionChanged)
```

да `self.mediaPlayer.position()` отличается от `self._position`.
используйте то что вам надо.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl, QSize
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaContent, QMediaPlayer
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget


class VideoWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(500, 500))
        self.resize(500, 500)
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.button = QPushButton('Play', self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.playMedia)
        button2 = QPushButton("Искать в текущей позиции", self)
        button2.clicked.connect(self.seekToCurrentPosition)
        
        video_widget = QVideoWidget(self)                                 # self
     
        self.mediaPlayer = QMediaPlayer(self, QMediaPlayer.VideoSurface)  # self
        self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(video_widget)
        self.mediaPlayer.setMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile("Samonastrojka.avi")))
        
        self._position = 0                                                                 # +++ !!!
        self.mediaPlayer.positionChanged.connect(self.positionChanged)                     # +++ !!!

        self.mainLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(video_widget)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(button2)

    def playMedia(self):
        print(f'\nplayMedia state 1: {self.mediaPlayer.state()} - '
              f'{self.mediaPlayer.position()} <--> {self._position}')
        if self.mediaPlayer.state() == QMediaPlayer.PlayingState:
            self.mediaPlayer.pause()
            self.button.setText('Play')
            print(f"current_position:      {self.mediaPlayer.position()} <--> {self._position}")
        else:
            self.mediaPlayer.play()
            self.button.setText('Pause')
        print(f'playMedia state 2: {self.mediaPlayer.state()} - {self.mediaPlayer.position()}'
              f' <--> {self._position}')

    def seekToCurrentPosition(self):
        print(f'\nseekToCurrentPosition state:      {self.mediaPlayer.state()}- '
              f'{self.mediaPlayer.position()}<--> {self._position}')
        if self.mediaPlayer.state() != QMediaPlayer.PausedState:
            return
        
        current_pos = self.mediaPlayer.position()
        print(f'seekToCurrentPosition current_pos 1: {current_pos}<--> {self._position}')
        self.mediaPlayer.setPosition(current_pos)
        print(f'seekToCurrentPosition current_pos 2: {self.mediaPlayer.position()}<--> {self._position}')

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
    def positionChanged(self, position):
        self._position = position                                          # <<<-------<
#        print(self._position)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    player = VideoWindow()
    player.show()
    exitCode = app.exec_()
    sys.exit(exitCode)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Да у Вас действительно получается два разных значения. Self._position()  - значение до паузы меньшее, чем после паузы и если использовать его, то откидывать будет еще дальше. Суть в том, что реальный поток после паузы находится на 1-2 кадра дальше, а не ближе, то есть реальное значение должно быть больше значения после паузы. Скорей всего это баг самого проигрывателя.